# Dynamically pulling in content block with variable

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm printing my variable in the body as such: %%=v(@complianceblock)=%%

And hoping to get the specific content block I need to populate it. Currently, I am missing something as I cannot get it to generate the proper output.

I'm using the following to get the compliance variable:

```
%%[
VAR @id, @complianceblock, @preference

SET @id = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
SET @preference = Lookup.......

IF @preference == 'Y' THEN
SET @complianceblock = "%%=ContentBlockbyId("...")=%%"

ELSE 

SET @complianceblock = "%%%%=ContentBlockbyId("...")=%%"

ENDIF
]%%
```

Is there a better way of tackling this?

Comment: The lookup part, which you skipped, is the most error prone part of the script. It would be good if you could show the whole thing, plus the structure of the Data Extension used in the lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need all the percent signs inside of the AMPscript block. Take a look at this example from the [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/contentblockbyid/):

```
%%[

var @contentBlockID
set @contentBlockID = 5794 /* Content Builder\LoyaltyGreeting */

]%%
%%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%
```

So, in your case, you need to define the content block inside of the if/else statement, and then display it outside of the AMPscript block using     `%%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%`. Something like this should work:

```
%%[
VAR @id, @complianceblock, @preference

SET @id = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
SET @preference = Lookup.......

IF @preference == 'Y' THEN
SET @complianceblock = 123

ELSE 

SET @complianceblock = 456

ENDIF
]%%

%%=ContentBlockByID(@complianceblock)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and helps clarify the example for me!

Comment: for some reason, the resulting content will always indent, leaving a little left padding. If I type anything, it works as intended, but one I insert the contentblock code, it indents left. I have all blocks matching the same styling. Have you come across this before?